# Download a vcf file from and ASP.Net MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view with a link to a .vcf file that I would like users to download.
The issue is when I am browsing the site on a mobile device it displays the file and does not download it.

I have tried add a response header to the top of the view but it then downloads it automatically when the page loads and not on click of the download link.

```
@{
var tag = Tag(Model, "div");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + item.Agents.AutoroutePart.Path + ".vcf");
}
<div><a href="~/themes/bootstrap/content/@item.Agents.AutoroutePart.Path@T(".vcf")">add</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not on your page that you need to add that header, it's to the resource itself. The page has only a link to the resource. There's going to be a second request for the file when the user clicks the link. That second request, the one for the file itself, is the one that needs the additional header.

You can add that header either by serving it from a custom action, or you can write a filter that adds the header when it sees requests for that file.

Finally, small detail: your usage of the T method doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. T is for localization, and I'm having a hard time understanding why a file extension would have to vary per culture...